# Switch case string not being displayed when combobox option is clicked

Tags: java, combobox, switch-statement

I am testing this code to ensure it runs as intended before i finish the rest of the switch cases. The application runs fine, but when the combo box option is clicked it is supposed to display a string based on the appropriate case. I cannot figure out why this isn't working. I tried debugging but frankly i didn't see any issues. Any help would be great. Here is the code:

```
 package combobox;

 import java.awt.*;
 import java.awt.event.*;
 import javax.swing.*;

 public class SolicitorComBox extends JFrame implements ActionListener {
 String[] MuniArray = {"Allepo", "Avalon",};
 JComboBox MuniList = new JComboBox (MuniArray);
 JLabel lblText = new JLabel();

 public static void main(String[] args) {
    SolicitorComBox fr = new SolicitorComBox();
    centerFrame(fr);
    fr.setVisible(true);


 }
 private static void centerFrame(SolicitorComBox fr) {


 }
 public SolicitorComBox() {
    setLayout (new FlowLayout());
    setSize (400, 300);
    setTitle ("Solicitor Search");
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    MuniList.setSelectedIndex(0);
    MuniList.addActionListener(this);
    add(MuniList);
    add(lblText);

}
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    if (e.getSource() == MuniList) {
        JComboBox cb = (JComboBox).e.getSource();
        String msg = (String)cb.getSelectedItem();
        switch (msg) {
            case "Allepo": lblText.setText("The attorney is Joe!");
            break;
            case "Avalon": lblText.setText("The attorney is Dana!");
            break;
```

Comment: `(JComboBox).e.getSource()` won't compile, can you include a working example?

Comment: Im sorry, Peter i'm new here so bare with me and my confusion lol. Do you mean like a screenshot of the application running?

Comment: You should add some debugging to see if your "if" statement gets executed and what the "msg" value actually is. With that you can debug where the problem resides.

@JoeBarrett he wants the full code for this class file there is more code below case "Avalon": etc...

Comment: @JeremyTrifilo if i am correct, its saying that the if statement is not being exicuted because JComboBox cannot be resolved to a variable in line 37. Im not sure how to fix this any suggestions? Also there is no further code below avalon.

Comment: You said the "application runs fine" but the code you gave doesn't even compile, so it won't run at all.

Comment: @PeterLawrey The code compiled fine for me. The issue was that the label text was not displaying when an option was clicked in the drop down box. Another user discovered i had an extra period where i wasn't supposed to, which resolved the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `actionPerformed()` change

```
(JComboBox).e.getSource();
```

to

```
(JComboBox) e.getSource();
```

you must do a cast to JComboBox

Comment: Yeah that fixes his problem for sure just compiled his code and he had a "." where it wasn't suppose to be.